# Replicate row by n times being n a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

Imagine I have the following data:

```
    Index   Local ID    Number of Dependents
0   PT1      362               2.0
1   PT2      363               1.0
2   PT3      369               3.0
3   PT4      373               2.0
```

How can I replicate the rows of the dataframe n times being n the value in the column "Number of Dependents"? and change the value in the column all to "1" (without the .0). The expected result would be:

```
    Index   Local ID    Number of Dependents
0   PT1      362               1
0   PT1      362               1
1   PT2      363               1
2   PT3      369               1
2   PT3      369               1
2   PT3      369               1
3   PT4      373               1
3   PT4      373               1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Follow the solution in the duplicate then assign 1 in the column